# Extending/Merging object

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, object

I'm currently trying to Extend/Push/Merge an object using AngularJS my problem is, when I do extend it's adding one object with an Index of 0 and I cannot add anymore as they all get the same index of 0

```
//Original Object
{ "groups": { 
            "1": { "id": "1", "name": "object1"},
            "2": { "id": "2", "name": "object2"}
            }
}

//After running function
{ "groups": { 
            "0": { "id": "1", "name": "object0"}, //This is the new object no more can then be added
            "1": { "id": "1", "name": "object1"},
            "2": { "id": "2", "name": "object2"}
            }
}

//What I want
{ "groups": {                
            "1": { "id": "1", "name": "object1"},
            "2": { "id": "2", "name": "object2"},
            "3": { "id": "3", "name": "object3"},
            "4": { "id": "4", "name": "object4"} // etc
            }
}
```

I'm currently using this:

```
$scope.addGroup = function () {

    angular.extend($scope.audit.groups,[
        {
                "name": "",
                "questions": []
            }
        ]);
}
```

jsfiddle = https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/23760/

The PHP Object is currently being built like this if restructuring this will help I'm more than willing to do that.

```
public function getAllQuestionGroupsByAuditIdArray($id) {

    $questions = new Question();
    foreach ($this->getAllQuestionGroupsByAuditId($id) AS $key => $group) {

        $QuestionGroups[$key] = array(
            "id" => $group['id'],
            "name" => $group['name'],
            "questions" => $questions->getQuestionsByGroupIdArray($group['id'])
        );
    }


    return $QuestionGroups;
}

$this->response = array(
        "name" => $auditData['name'],
        "groups" => $questionGroups->getAllQuestionGroupsByAuditIdArray($id),
    );
return print_r(json_encode($this->response));
```

Comment: Can `groups` not be an array of objects?

Comment: I've added the PHP I'm using to create the object in the first place.

Comment: So the question remains, is the `$key` of importance? If not, then you can make groups an array rather than an object. [For example](https://jsfiddle.net/1yz3urh7/)

Comment: Bah, Thank you. You've made me rethink my PHP code using array_push instead fixes this issue completely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PHP we can update the response to return a non-associative array or groups like so:

```
$QuestionGroups = array();
foreach ($this->getAllQuestionGroupsByAuditId($id) AS $key => $group) {
    $QuestionGroups[] = array(
        "id" => $group['id'],
        "name" => $group['name'],
        "questions" => $questions->getQuestionsByGroupIdArray($group['id'])
    );
}
```

When converted to JSON this will return `groups` as an array of objects rather than an object of objects.

You can then simply use `.push()` to append more groups into the `groups` array.

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1yz3urh7/)